# Continuous "hot" deployment of an angular web app

Tags: node.js, angularjs, deployment, web-deployment

How to deploy a new version of an AngularJS single page web app (API based) without interrupting service ?

We need at last :

- to update the sources (server and client)
- to migrate/update the database
- to relaunch the server

Even with a load balancer and at last 2 rotating servers (one updating while the other is serving), I can't figure a safe way to deploy a new version without interrupting service and without losing user data.

Imagine a user working on a complex document in our web app. We can't force reload its page during its work session...

How to do it ?
If not possible, how to mitigate the issue ?

Comment: Conceptually, you could use a load balancer that includes session management, so you can switch the user to another server w/o interrupting the session.  I've had one client that had a setup like that; but they had network guys who took care of the specifics.  This might be a better question on Server Fault?

Comment: @Reboog711 and what about the db schéma ? (even on NoSQL) We can't keep two different software versions in sync...

Comment: It depends on your environment; I suppose.  I believe there are ways to load balance database servers too.  So, take down one DB Server and one application server.  Update both.  Bring them back up at the same time you take the other set down.

Comment: @Reboog711 and then all new data created during the switch is lost :-/

Comment: Interesting link http://sandinmyjoints.github.io/towards-100-pct-uptime/#/17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Server side

Well, it would be much much easier to make your service **stateless** and move session to **client side** - you will not need to poke with sessions at all (this approach has it's own drawbacks though).

### Client side

In this case you will need a **round-robin** load balancer (the most simple one) with healthchecks. And then you will be able to update the serverside easily one by one.

Whether you need service restart or not during the **clientside update** (which is simple static assets swap) depends on the webserver you are using to server the assets.

### Database

The database integrity is a tough topic. One way to achieve this is creating the DB replication cluster - **master and slave servers**. When you master is down, one of the slaves are serving the client. When the master is up, slaves push the intermittent data back to master and give the master its privilege to serve the client. How to do that? *That's the real question :)*

Some databases support **binary schema evolution** - they can update the data from replicas to master with regard to schema changes.

Some databases has **live schema support**, but it is still very limited.

### Workarounds

As you have a **document edit functionality** and no realtime updates/reads, you can **cache user's data** on the client (using localStorage, for example).

All modifications can be stored as **deltas**, modifying the database state (something similar to **event sourcing**).

Or you can just store the **whole document model** (deltas are must-have for collaborative edit).

While you are getting the erroneous response from the server during the save process, you just keep relying on the client's cache.

*Don't forget to indicate your user that he can lose some data as you are experiencing connection troubles.* This is for good UX.

### Resume

**There are no silver bullet** in each of those facets. The process steps always depends on the project context.

The update process should be thought up in advance and be a part of system design activity.

Comment: Now I have much to ponder... Thanks for adressing the DB issue !